# How to fix StreamlitAPIException: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column value with type object')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

**Error**: `StreamlitAPIException: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column value with type object')`

**Traceback**: `File "/Users/temporaryadmin/Streamlit_app_v.1/streamlit_app_v1/main.py", line 48, in <module> st.line_chart(df)`

**Problem**:
I'm quite new to this and got quite excited with this first Streamlit project off mine. The file runs fine with I don't include the `pandas_data = {'County': county_names}` but the list of strings stored in "county_names" is quite crucial to representing the data in the graph.

Any help in what to do would be highly appreciated, thank you. `enter code here`

**Here is my code**:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import requests

bas_url = 'https://services1.arcgis.com/eNO7HHeQ3rUcBllm/arcgis/rest/services/Covid19CountyStatisticsHPSCIrelandOpenData/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=CountyName,PopulationCensus16,ConfirmedCovidCases,PopulationProportionCovidCases&outSR=4326&f=json'
response = requests.get(bas_url)
print(response)
get_json_response = requests.get(bas_url).json()

data = []
for i in get_json_response['features']:
    data.append(i)

# List comprehension
new_data = [i['attributes'] for i in data]

#  All variables below containing lists of data from api request
county_names = [i['CountyName'] for i in new_data]
population_total_2016 = [i['PopulationCensus16'] for i in new_data]
confirmed_cases = [i['ConfirmedCovidCases'] for i in new_data]

pandas_data = {
    'County': county_names,
    'Population': population_total_2016,
    'Confirmed cases': confirmed_cases
}

df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_data)
st.write(df)
st.line_chart(df)
```

Comment: what are you trying to plot? population and confirmed cases for each county? because your data doesn't fit for a line plot.

Comment: What is the graph you are wanting to create? `streamlit.line_chart` is expecting number values for the x or y axis not the names of the counties

Comment: @RoseGod 
Thank you for your comments, maybe I should be looking to make a different chart. I will look into making a bar chart and other charts that are possible. Thanks

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe do you know if it's possible to make a chart with the counties as part of the dataframe? Like for example, counties on the x axis and population on the y axis as bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a bar chart with counties on the x axis by reshaping your data like this

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import requests

bas_url = 'https://services1.arcgis.com/eNO7HHeQ3rUcBllm/arcgis/rest/services/Covid19CountyStatisticsHPSCIrelandOpenData/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=CountyName,PopulationCensus16,ConfirmedCovidCases,PopulationProportionCovidCases&outSR=4326&f=json'
response = requests.get(bas_url)
print(response)
get_json_response = requests.get(bas_url).json()

data = []
for i in get_json_response['features']:
    data.append(i)

# List comprehension
new_data = [i['attributes'] for i in data]

#  All variables below containing lists of data from api request
county_names = [str(i['CountyName']) for i in new_data]
population_total_2016 = [i['PopulationCensus16'] for i in new_data]
confirmed_cases = [i['ConfirmedCovidCases'] for i in new_data]

pandas_data = {
    'County': county_names,
    'Population': population_total_2016,
    'Confirmed cases': confirmed_cases
}

df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_data)
df = df.groupby('County')[['Population', 'Confirmed cases']].sum()
st.write(df)
st.bar_chart(df)
```

Grouping the dataframe and making the counties the dataframe's index will tell `streamlit` to use them as your x axis and then will use the values in `Population` and `Confirmed cases` to make the bars.

And the graph would look like this:
[image: Stacked Barchart showing population and cases]

Comment: That's great thank you so much!